# Tracking the results of the multiprosssing version of the for-loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function that I apply sequentially on a list of objects and which returns me a score for each object as following :

```
def get_score(a):
    // do something
   return score

objects = [obj0, obj1, obj3]
results = np.zeros(len(objects))
index = 0
for i in range(len(results)):
    results[i]=get_score(objects[i])
```

I want to parallelize the execution of this function whith Multiprocessing library, but I have a question, how can I tell that such a score corresponds to such an object since I will not have a shared results list ?

Comment: "but I have a question, how can I tell that such a score corresponds to such an object since I will not have a shared results list ?" I don't understand what you mean by this. What exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to return the index and processed object (score) from the `get_score` function.

Example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


def get_score(tpl):
    i, (par1, par2) = tpl

    # do something
    return i, f"{par1=} {par2=} processed"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    par1 = ["obj1", "obj2", "obj3"]
    par2 = ["par2_1", "par2_2", "par2_3"]
    # ...

    results = [None] * len(par1)

    with Pool() as p:
        # process the objects in unordered fashion
        for i, result in p.imap_unordered(get_score, enumerate(zip(par1, par2))):
            results[i] = result

    print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[
    "par1='obj1' par2='par2_1' processed",
    "par1='obj2' par2='par2_2' processed",
    "par1='obj3' par2='par2_3' processed",
]
```

Comment: why do it this way? Why not `p.map`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's other option, yes. But I guess `Pool.map` holds the object in memory (to return them in correct order - could cause memory issues?)

Comment: Thanks. I have another question, what about the case when `get_score` take four parameters ?

Comment: @ZchGarinch Just pass 4 parameters to `get_score(tpl)` and then you can unpack it inside, e.g. `par1, par2, par3, par4 = tpl`

Comment: Thanks, but how can i create this tpl ?each object in my list will be processed by the same four parameters. Could I incorporate theses param in the enumerate function ?

Comment: @ZchGarinch If you have your parameters in four different lists, you can use `zip()` to tie them together. You can combine `enumerate` + `zip` too.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with the use of enumerate + zip ?

Comment: @ZchGarinch I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get these runs : `get_score(obj1, par1, par2 ,par3, par4)`, `get_score(obj2, par1,par2,par3,par4)`.

Comment: @ZchGarinch The principle is the same. You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for example.

Comment: I dont see how use this function, may be create a list of tuple ? (obj,par1,..par4)  and enumerate over this ?

Comment: @ZchGarinch Yes, depends on the use case. Its perfectly ok to create tuples in form `(obj,par1,..par4)` and enumerate over them. Or if you want to cycle some variables, use `cycle` etc.

Comment: How do you create efficiently such tuple from two lists ? (obj, list_params) ? `oo = [(x,params) for x in objects]`  is this the best way ?

Comment: @ZchGarinch e.g. `enumerate((o, par1, par2, par3, par4) for o in ["obj1", "obj2", ...])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255450/discussion-between-zchgarinch-and-andrej-kesely).